# Were Maxwell's equations first formulated by McCullough?

Tags: history, maxwell-equations

Some years ago, I heard a talk about a an Irish or Scottish physicist named McCullough who had formulated Maxwell's equations several years before Maxwell.  This fellow was recognized for his work, according to the talk, by systematically discounted by other luminaries of the day like Stokes and Hamilton in favor of Maxwell.  At some point, he was found with his throat cut for no apparent reason.

I can find no mention of McCullough anywhere and I am wondering if this story is at all true.  I may have some details wrong; the talk was several years ago.  If anyone knows anything, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic here, but if it is, I've edited it to improve the title.

Comment: Possibly related: http://www.hamilton.tcd.ie/events/MacCullagh_talk.pdf

Comment: Feynman in his Lectures on Physics and his Nobel Lecture (December 11, 1965) gave a little bit wrong spelling - MacCullough. Really it's Ireland born professor James MacCullagh: Whittaker E.T., A history of the Theories of Aether and Electricity, LONGMANS, GREEN, AND CO.,London, HODGES, FIGGIS, & CO., Ltd., DUBLIN, 1910, Pg. 154. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_MacCullagh You can read his original works here:
https://archive.org/details/collectedworks00maccuoft